# How do I fix the "You're attempting to access the site via IP address or invalid hostname." error?

Tags: 7, configuration

I'm running Drupal 7 on Pantheon and have started getting the following error message whenever I try to save content.

> You're attempting to access a Pantheon site via IP address or invalid hostname. Please use a valid hostname.

I've found a number of related issues online:

- [Drupal.org Trusted Host settings](https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal/trusted-host-settings)
- [How to fix "The provided host name is not valid for this server" in
  Drupal](https://www.thesavvyfew.com/insights/how-fix-provided-host-name-not-valid-server-drupal#:%7E:text=Here%27s%20what%20it%20means%20and%20how%20to%20fix%20it.&text=This%20error%20message%20is%20caused,it%20to%20be%20someone%20else.)
- [How do I use a settings.local.php file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235719/how-to-use-settings-local-php-with-drupal-7)
- [What does "The provided host name is not valid for this server" mean?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145286/what-does-the-provided-host-name-is-not-valid-for-this-server-mean)

Most of these articles reference Drupal 7, but all of the fixes are for Drupal 8.

I'm experiencing this problem in both dev and in production (though user interactions on the live site seem to be fine, thank goodness). It started a week ago, and now I'm functionally locked out from creating new content or editing most of the site. It affects all of my browsers, both of my laptops and occurs whether I'm connecting via wifi or tethering data from my phone (a separate ISP), so this isn't a local issue.

How do I resolve it for Drupal 7?

Update: This issue appears to be related to Microsoft's massive July 2021 bug fix update last week. I'll leave this here in case anyone else is experiencing the same issue.

Comment: If you are linking to another question on this site, please actually post the link in your question.

Comment: Ah sorry - they were in my draft elsewhere. I'll update them.

Comment: Probably something to ask the Pantheon support about.

Comment: They're looking at it, but not much they can do since the issue is ultimately local (though it affects all of my Windows10 systems).

Comment: Did you ever find the answer @tonka69?

Comment: @Webdrips, if you're still looking, it turned out that Bitdefender was throwing the issue. Other than that, Pantheon wasn't able to help, saying it was a js issue from one of my installed modules. It eventually cleared on its own.